# configuring rake to use correct coffee path

Tags: rake, coffeescript

I'm using rake to compile coffeescript to javascript.

I found that rake is trying to run coffee from `/usr/local/bin/coffee` but coffee is actually installed in the location `/usr/bin/coffee`.

How can I configure rake to use the actual path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
`which coffee` -c ...
```

Then it find either the local coffee-script or global depending on how you installed it with npm

Comment: Or more directly, `env coffee -c ...`